# Connect Firebase to MySQL to copy/mirror data added to firebase

Tags: mysql, firebase

I have a firebase database and i want to connect it to a mysql database to store every data that is being added to the firebase to be stored directly into the mysql database

Waiting for a proper method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, what did you try?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I tried the standard way of using nodeJS but I was hoping to get a much simple method like using an API

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? Firebase (either the Realtime Database or Firestore) is a very robust, performant, scalable database. Why duplicate all of that data in MySQL? There is no way to directly do that either but you can code your app to do it! You're have to re-think your structure, references and develop those into relationships instead - that's a lot of extra work. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the standard way of using nodeJS but I was hoping to get a
> much simple method like using an API (from above comments).

There's no API for transferring/mirroring [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) (or [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)) data to a MySQL DB instance. You need to code this data transfer yourself.

Among possible solutions, you could write a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that uses the Admin SDK for Node.js to write to your MySQL DB.

Comment: Could You provide a summary on the method and maybe a few steps. Much appreciated